# Ensuring that attributes referenced by a mixin are present in the children class

Tags: python, inheritance, mixins

I have implemented the below `_get_schema` method to ensure that `schema` attribute is always present on the `Todos` instance, and can therefore be used in the mixin.

Is it OK to do it like this? As far as I know, mixins usually do not implement constructors.

Is there a better way to make sure that someone did not forget to explicitly set the `schema` attribute in the `Todos` class, especially that this attribute is also not inherited from `View`?

```
class Mixin:
    def __init__(self):
        self._get_schema()
        super().__init__()

    def _get_schema(self):
        if not hasattr(self, 'schema'):
            msg = f'No "schema" attribute provided in {self.__class__.__name__} class'
            raise Exception(msg)

class View:
    def __init__(self):
        print('view constructor')

class Todos(SchemaMixin, MethodView):
    schema = 'todo schema'

todos = Todos()
```

Comment: Your code looks like it has errors (two Mixin definitions, for example). Also, where does the scheme come from -- passed as argument, read from an external source, etc? How many classes will inherit from the schema-checking mixin(s) in question?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, duplicate code is now deleted. The scheme will come only from setting it as class attribute like in my example. Rest of the implementation is inherited from my mixin and generic Flask's MethodView. My intention is to have a couple of classes that inherit from the mixin and method view like that, each class representing a specific resource in the database.

Comment: Does `SchemaMixin` do anything besides verify the class has a schema attribute? Does the check need to be done at runtime or is a compile time check okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the norm is to just try to access the `schema` attribute and let it fail with an AttributeError if there isn't one. But here are two possibilities to catch it before runtime (at compile time, or using a type checker).

#### Using `__init_subclass__()`

This may be a good use case for adding an [`__init_subclass__()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__init_subclass__#object.__init_subclass__) method to the mixin class. It will get called (at compile time) whenever a class inherits the mixin.

```
class SchemaMixin:
    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        if not hasattr(cls, 'schema'):
            raise Exception(f"class {cls.__name__} is missing a 'schema' attribute.")

    def do_something_with_the_schema(self, *args):
        # method can rely on self having a 'schema' attribute.
        print(self.schema)
            
class Todo(SchemaMixin):
    schema = "testing"
    
class BadTodo(SchemaMixin):
    pass
```

When Python tries to compile class `BadTodo`, it will raise the following exception (traceback omitted):

```
Exception: class BadTodo is missing a 'schema' attribute.
```

#### Using type hints

If you are using type hints, this might be checked using [PEP 544 Protocols](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/) to define structural subtyping.

```
from typing import Protocol

class Schema(Protocol):
    schema: ClassVar[str]
```

Functions/methods that need a type that has a schema attribute would use Schema as a type hint:

```
def use_a_schema(x: Schema) -> some_type_hint:
    print(x.schema)
```

And a type checker like mypy could verify that it is called with arguments having a `schema` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The point of a mixin, at least as I've always understood it, is to inject
methods into other classes -- and not to create instances of the mixin class
itself. So putting an `__init__()` in a mixin does seem like an odd pattern. Of
course, `__init__()` is just a method: why not inject that method too? Fair
enough, but it still feels off. And is it really necessary?

One option is to inject the schema checking method and then call it in a proper
`__init__()`:

```
class SchemaMixin:

    def _check_schema(self):
        ...

class Todos(SchemaMixin):

    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self._check_schema()
```

Or just use regular functions and get out of the awkward business of
inheritance. Without knowing more details about your case, I would lean in this
direction.

```
def check_schema(obj):
    ...

class Todos():

    def __init__(self):
        check_schema(self)
```

I find myself almost never using inheritance these days -- regular or
mixin-style. I don't have a blanket policy against it, but I increasingly find
that I just don't need it. If a class needs something, I pass it in as an
argument. If multiple classes need the same operation, I use functions.

Comment: Thanks! Regarding "if a class needs something, I pass it in as an argument" - is it doable in this case, since Todos is just a class called by the framework whenever certain URL is hit, and I have no control over what arguments are passed to its constructor?